# jquery/javascript initiation of File download with MVC custom BufferedMediaTypeFormatter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, download, mediatypeformatter

I have a web api which is returning me a user list based on (at the moment) some simple search criteria.

```
 public class UserListAPIController : APIController
{

    public List<UserManagerSearchResult> Get(int siteGroupId)
    {
        return userService.UserManagerSearch(LoggedInUserToken.DefaultSiteID, siteGroupId);
    }
}
```

This is called from the client knockoutjs viewmodel using an ajax getJson request with a dynamically generated url based on the various filter criteria selected.

```
  self.LoadUsers = function () {

    var SiteGroupID = self.selectedSiteGroup();
    $.getJSON("/API/UserListAPI/?siteGroupId=" + SiteGroupID
        , function (allData) {
        var mappedUsers = $.map(allData, function (item) {
           //mapping code
            return dbu;

        });
        self.Users(mappedUsers);
    });
};
```

This then uses the knockout template binding to display the results nicely in a grid.

I also need to implement a "download to csv" feature which will return the exact same results as selected for the ui search listing.

So my idea was to implement a custom mediatypeformatter which would allow me to execute the same web api but return a csv response rather than a json response.

I have implemented and tested this in fiddler and is working as expected.so when I set the type to 'text/csv' and call the web api I get the csv results.

```
public class UserManagerSearchResultCSVFormatter : BufferedMediaTypeFormatter 
{

    public UserManagerSearchResultCSVFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return false; 
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(UserManagerSearchResult))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Type enumerableType = typeof(List<UserManagerSearchResult>);
            return enumerableType.IsAssignableFrom(type);
        }


    }

    public override void WriteToStream(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream,
                                       System.Net.Http.HttpContent content)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
        {
            var results = value as List<UserManagerSearchResult>;
            if (results != null)
            {
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    WriteItem(result, writer);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var result = value as UserManagerSearchResult;
                if (result == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot serialize type");
                }
                WriteItem(result, writer);
            }
        }
        writeStream.Close();
    }


    // Helper methods for serializing Products to CSV format. 
    private void WriteItem(UserManagerSearchResult result, StreamWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", Escape(result.UserId),
            Escape(result.UserName), Escape(result.Year));
    }

    static char[] _specialChars = new char[] { ',', '\n', '\r', '"' };

    private string Escape(object o)
    {
        if (o == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        string field = o.ToString();
        if (field.IndexOfAny(_specialChars) != -1)
        {
            return String.Format("\"{0}\"", field.Replace("\"", "\"\""));
        }
        else return field;
    }

}
```

That is all the background.

I have hit a couple of issues which I don't know how best to implement.

Firstly in order for this to work I need to be able to do the following :
1. dynamically build up the url (as seen for the ajax getjson example above) 
2. set the type of request to 'text/csv'
3. initite the call to the url  with the request type and force a download of the file.

This is pretty much were I am stuck as the best way to implement this. Ive been looking at some jquery ajax to try and achieve this but not getting very far and could do with someones opinions on the best way this can be implemented.